# postgresql insert statment taking 240+ ms to run for single insert in typescript express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, fp-ts

I am trying to test a db insert operation using mocha for an node.js express application that uses fp-ts and pg npm package.  I am running on my local machine and the db is in the digital ocean cloud.  The tests complete successfully but the insert test seems to take 240+ ms to complete.  The db table may have 12 records at most.  I could use a hand at narrowing down the likely culprit.

Mocha Test db initialization

```
before(() => {
    pool = new pg.Pool({
        user: process.env.USER_NAME,
        host: process.env.HOST_NAME,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT!)
    });
});
```

Mocha Test

```
it("It should save a User", () => {
    const userRepository = makeUserRepository(pool);

    return pipe(
        {
            emailAddress: 'jdoe123@anywhere.com',
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            password: 'slkfdjjfiwjfojisjsdlkfjksdlfjas'
        },
        userRepository.saveUser,
        fold(
            (error: ErrorBase) => async () => {
                console.time("dbsavepipeoperationerror");
                expect(error).to.be.null;
                console.timeEnd("dbsavepipeoperationerror");
            },
            (user: User) => async () => {
                console.time("dbsavepipeoperation");
                tempUserId = user.userId;
                expect(user).to.be.an('object');
                console.timeEnd("dbsavepipeoperation");
            }
        )
    )();
});
```

Repository function call that performs the save operation

```
const saveUser = (user: User): TaskEither<ErrorBase, User> => tryCatch(
    async () => {
        const paramList: string[] = [];
        const values: string[] = [];
        let queryString = ``;

        const {emailAddress, password, firstName, lastName} = user;

        if (emailAddress) {
            paramList.push("emailAddress");
            values.push(emailAddress);
        }

        if (password) {
            paramList.push("password");
            values.push(password);
        }

        if (firstName) {
            paramList.push("firstName");
            values.push(firstName);
        }

        if (lastName) {
            paramList.push("lastName");
            values.push(lastName);
        }

        queryString = `INSERT INTO "User"(` + paramList.map((param) => "\"" + param + "\"").join(",") + `)
            VALUES(` + paramList.map((param, i) => "$" + (++i)).join(",") + `)
            RETURNING *`;

        console.time("dbsave");
        const result: pg.QueryResult<User> = await pool.query(queryString, values);
        console.timeEnd("dbsave");
        return result?.rows[0];
    },
    (reason: any) => (
        {message: reason.message, name: reason.name, details: '', innerError: reason as Error}
    )
);
```

Here are the time durations for the insert and for the test to complete
User Repository Tests

```
dbsave: 237.2822265625 ms
dbsave: 237.451ms
dbsavepipeoperation: 0.114013671875 ms
dbsavepipeoperation: 0.19ms
    ✔ It should save a User (240ms)
```

For my package.json file, I am using the following script to run the tests

```
"test": "ts-mocha --config src/tests/runners/mocha/.mocharc.json --recursive --in-order --watch-recursive"
```

Update:
I added four new tests to determine if the pool establishing connections might be the culprit.  The first save took 263ms and the next three, including the one I was initially trying to run took 50+ ms.  Is there a way to force the pool to establish the connection before the queries need to run?  I thought that was what the pool was suppose to actually do?  If not, how can I force the connection upon pool creation as it seems as if the first query call is establishing it.

```
it("It should test the connection speed", async () => {
    let queryString = `INSERT INTO profile."User"("firstName", "lastName", "emailAddress")
            VALUES($1, $2, $3)
            RETURNING *`;

    const values = ['asdfasdfsad', 'asdfsadf', 'asdfasdfs@asfsdf.com'];
    const result: pg.QueryResult<User> = await pool.query(queryString, values);
    expect(result).to.be.an('object');
});

it("It should test the connection speed - 2", async () => {
    let queryString = `INSERT INTO profile."User"("firstName", "lastName", "emailAddress")
            VALUES($1, $2, $3)
            RETURNING *`;

    const values = ['asdfasdfsad', 'asdfsadf', 'asdfasdfs@asfsdf.com'];
    const result: pg.QueryResult<User> = await pool.query(queryString, values);
    expect(result).to.be.an('object');
});

it("It should test the connection speed - 3", async () => {
    let queryString = `INSERT INTO profile."User"("firstName", "lastName", "emailAddress")
            VALUES($1, $2, $3)
            RETURNING *`;

    const values = ['asdfasdfsad', 'asdfsadf', 'asdfasdfs@asfsdf.com'];
    const result: pg.QueryResult<User> = await pool.query(queryString, values);
    expect(result).to.be.an('object');
});


User Repository Tests
    ✔ It should test the connection speed (263ms)
    ✔ It should test the connection speed - 2 (46ms)
    ✔ It should test the connection speed - 3 (44ms)
    ✔ It should save an object - User (56ms)
```

Comment: Your query is probably creating a connection, signing in, and then running your query.  Those pools start out empty.  Could that be the culprit?  Maybe you should try isolating those two pieces so you can time them separately and see what you learn from that

Comment: The before() function above should perform the initial pool creation, I thought.  The test is injecting that pool variable to the repository layer or are you saying that pool is setup but the connection of not actually established until first use?

Comment: Yes. The pool is set up, but creating connections is 'lazy'.  Ie it is done only once it is actually needed.  Additional pool members are added (up until maximum), again, only once they are needed. That means, only once it happens to be the case that all existing pool connections are already in use.

Comment: Gotcha.  Will confirm.

Comment: After the findings I listed above in the Update section, what can I do to ensure the connection opens before I begin querying?

Comment: @user1790300 perhaps you can try opening a connection and making a basic query when you set up the pool on app startup? That might "prime" the pool so that any subsequent queries are faster.
Essentially you would be avoiding the "lazy" connection creation by forcing it to happen up-front manually.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing this here as an answer.  As we discussed in the comments, the `pg.Pool` is created with the capacity to run X simultaneous connections to the database and to help by managing the opening and closing of those connections.  New connection will only be opened when one is needed - ie the pool uses "Lazy" client creation.  Running a query will automatically create a client connection if one is needed or use an existing one if possible.

If you want to explicitly instantiate a connection from the pool, you can call `pool.connect` as shown in this example from the docs (https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool#poolconnect):

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg'
 
const pool = new Pool()
 
const client = await pool.connect()
await client.query('SELECT NOW()')
client.release()
```

As shown in the example, you should remember to return the client to the pool after you use it, by calling `release()`

Comment: Is there a way to force the connection to open long before the query call?  The issue is that the opening and reopening of the connection seems to be the culprit for the issue I listed above.  If I could somehow force the pool to open the connection at pool creation that might fix the issue.  For example, as this is an express app, can I open during bootstrapping phase/server creation and it stay open.